# codeigniter select as

Tags: php, codeigniter, select

how doHow do we do 
    `select table.value as table_value from table` in codeigniter?
The `AS` part doesnt work because when i try to access the value, 
this doesnt work:

```
    $qry_inp =  'select table.value as table_value from table '
    $query = $this->db->query($qry_inp); 

    echo $query->row('table_value ');// this will be empty, but it shouldn`t be
```

doesn`t matter if its in AR or simple query

Comment: See answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22969926/codeigniter-join-select-as

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where is that behaviour documented? `row` doesn't take a column name as a parameter; it [optionally takes a row number](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html), and that's it. Access it like any other field:

```
echo $query->row()->table_value;
```

Comment: that worked! oh and it wasnt documented, but it works like this too `$query->row('table_value ');` but only if you have one row returned. (found that in some blog)

Answer (score 10):

Pretty simple thing.

```
$this->db->select('COLUMN_ACTUAL_NAME as `COLUMN_NAME_YOU_WANT_TO_SHOW`');
```

Comment: What to do when we have two column like, proce_from & price_to now you want an average of this field and want an alias name also for this. how do I get this @Bugfixer

Answer (score 5):

i'm joining two tables in which column names are same so i separate both tables columns by using as keyword , this is how you can use AS in codeigniter

```js
$this->db->select("departments.name AS 'dname'");
$this->db->select('positions.name');
```