# CodeIgniter join select as

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have 2 tables in my database which I need to join.
1 table is the artikelen table and the other one is the collecties table. I currently have.

```
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('collecties');
  $this->db->join('artikelen', 'artikelen.collecties_id = collecties.id');
```

It gives the right result but all the double fields (collecties has a title field and artikelen has a title field) will become one (it returns the artikelen.title field), and I can't access the row of the other table (the collecties.title field).

I select 10 fields from artikelen and only collecties.title from collecties.

What is the simples way to do this without having to replace

```
    $this->db->select('*');
```

with all the 10 fields with an as statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure your both table got rows on your joining condition , otherwise it will return null. and modify the select as follows
      `$this->db->select('artikelen.*,collecties.title as ctitle');`

Comment: Thanks nice and easy solution, i was scared that i had to make an as statement for every field in artikelen.